# PostgreSQL optimization: Sequantial Scan VS Index Scan

Tags: postgresql, explain

I have one interesting case with select on postgres table:

```
advert (~2.5 million records)
    id serial,
    user_id integer (foreign key),
    ...
```

Here is my select:

```
select count(*) from advert where user_id in USER_IDS_ARRAY
```

And if `USER_IDS_ARRAY` length <= 100 I have next explain analyze:

```
Aggregate  (cost=18063.36..18063.37 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.362..0.362 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using ix__advert__user_id on advert  (cost=0.55..18048.53 rows=5932 width=0) (actual time=0.030..0.351 rows=213 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (user_id = ANY ('{(...)}'))
        Heap Fetches: 213
Planning time: 0.457 ms
Execution time: 0.392 ms
```

But when `USER_IDS_ARRAY` length > 100:

```
Aggregate  (cost=424012.09..424012.10 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=867.438..867.438 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on advert  (cost=0.00..423997.11 rows=5992 width=0) (actual time=0.375..867.345 rows=213 loops=1)
        Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{(...)}'))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2201318
Planning time: 0.261 ms
Execution time: 867.462 ms
```

No matter what user_ids in USER_IDS_ARRAY, only it's length matters.

Does anybody have ideas how to optimize this select for more then 100 user_ids?

Comment: Have you tried just selecting from `advert` without the join? Filter with > 100 user IDs and see if it uses the index or not.

Comment: @Sevanteri yes, you are right, the same situation with advert select. Simplified my question with one table only.

Comment: Right. It seems that the query planner just thinks that it is better to do a seq scan instead. You could run [`analyze`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html) for the tables and see if it helps.

Comment: @Sevanteri analyze on advert didn't help

Comment: you can disable seqscan for this query: `SET enable_seqscan = OFF; SELECT ...; SET enable_seqscan = ON;`

Comment: @ckruse For testing purposes yes, but not something you should rely on. [See the documentation here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE).

Comment: Why do you think doing e.g. 200 separate index lookups is faster than one scan of the whole table? Or 2000? At some point it needs to switch. Set enable_seqscan=OFF and we'll be able to see what costs PG estimates.

Comment: @ckruse  `SET enable_seqscan = OFF` didn't help

Comment: @RichardHuxton, I agree, but why `count(*)` on 100 users_ids continues less than `1ms`, when on 101 user_ids almost `1s`?

Comment: Show the definition of `ix__advert__user_id`.

Comment: @JakubKania Oh my God, you are right, I've forgot that this index is partial!!! `CREATE INDEX ix__advert__user_id ON advert USING btree (user_id) WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL;`
So I've used it in wrong way!
So many thanks from me.

Comment: @JakubKania, make you comment as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @VitaliPonomar Well...Okay, I added a few words of explanation.

Comment: `rows=5992 ... (actual ... rows=213` Looks like your statistics are off (or the column has a very strange spread of values) On second thought: ... I see/read : partial index... with the same effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `SET enable_seqscan = OFF` still doesn't force index scan it means the index scan is not possible. It turns out here the index was partial.